# Can someone help me install Bitconnect Wallet (tar file) on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04

I tried to install Bitconnect Wallet (tar file) on my Ubuntu 14.04, but it is not working. I followed some instructions on a YouTube video and I was still unable to install. Links are provided below. I would greatly appreciate your help, thanks!

Bitconnect Wallet (Bitconnect-Ubuntu14-64bit.tar): https://github.com/bitconnectcoin/bitconnectcoin/tree/master/setup/bitconnect-linux-wallet

YouTube video (Ultimate Guide : INSTALLING A PGM FROM .TAR FILES !!!): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W9JcK70kThI

Comment: Exactly at which step are you failing? What kind of error message(s) are you getting?

Comment: I was able to get through the first step and afterward I was unable to get anywhere. I am new to installing any tar files. Not sure what to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)

Comment: A TAR is just like a RAR or a ZIP, a (typically compressed) container that can have anything inside. Knowing that, what's inside IS what matters and nothing else. Keep this in mind for the future and meanwhile follow the answer below for your specific case (not necessarily applicable in other situations). Also if that answer helps you should accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step by step:

1.Download your software to `/tmp/Bitconnect-Ubuntu14-64bit.tar`

```
wget https://github.com/bitconnectcoin/bitconnectcoin/blob/master/setup/bitconnect-linux-wallet/Bitconnect-Ubuntu14-64bit.tar?raw=true -O /tmp/Bitconnect-Ubuntu14-64bit.tar
```

2.Open terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> and enter commands

```
cd /tmp 
tar -xvf Bitconnect-Ubuntu14-64bit.tar
sudo ./install.sh
sudo apt-get install libqt5widgets5
```

here:

- `cd /tmp` changes directory to `/tmp`;
- `tar -xvf` extracts `Bitconnect-Ubuntu14-64bit.tar` file (`-x` - eXtract, `-v` - verbose, `-f` - filename);
- `sudo ./install.sh` launches installation script to install program system-wide;
- `sudo apt-get install libqt5widgets5` installs necessary Qt5 system dependencies.

3.You can find installed application in **Applications** menu or launch it from terminal with `bitconnect-qt`.